# PHP PDO Iteration

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to iterate over a query result from a table of millions of entries by using `PDOStatement::fetch`, but it takes too long time:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select * from logs');
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // some stuff...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to iterate over the query results one by one instead of loading the whole result? Thanks!

Comment: huh? You are receiving one row one by one?! `fetchAll()` would get all results at one.

Comment: Of course it takes long to iterate over millions of entries, I'd recommend adding a paginator. DataTables.net is a nice plugin which you can use for this.

Comment: If I fetch by "select * from logs limit 100", it returns one by one. But when I remove "limit", it's too long.

Comment: @NishantSolanki Don't give lame advice that won't speed it up at all, that's just another way to fetch the rows.

Comment: @NishantSolanki Well you'll need a foreach to loop through the `fetchAll` which basically results in the same loading time, I've actually tested once which is faster, conclusion: `$stmt->fetch()`

Comment: why don't you limit the result and paginate, I don't think getting millions of rows in one go is good.

Comment: @Daan I did the same test and actully fount `fetch()` much faster than `fetchAll()`. thanks for the info :), I didnt know that this would happen

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided you are iterating rows one by one, and that is exactly as it should be done. You will have to consider other options for optimization depending on `stuff` you are doing with logs:

1. Reports, statistics - move some logic to SQL query, maybe a database can do it much faster.
2. Offline processing - partition the logs fetched and analyze it ex. once a day.
3. Displaying - paginate the results with SQL `limit` and `offset`.

We will be able to help more if you tell us what are you doing with logs.

Comment: Thanks @Furgas! Actually I want to modify a field (data) for all entries in the table (in this question I called it "logs", whatever). So I have to paginate the results, right?

Comment: @micmia It depends on scope of modification and if it's one-time or periodic. Some simple modifications can be done using one SQL update. If it's too complicated you will have to update them in parts or just wait as long as it takes. Maybe the contents of foreach needs optimization too, little drop in one record processing can impact whole script processing time when dealing with so many records. The conclusion is - there is no problem with the iteration alone.

Answer (score 0):

Its in no doubt pagination will come using ajax and likes will sort out your issues.Have a look at [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) Server-side processing. I have to admit it is wide but once you get around to use it things will be smooth.

Have a look at [this](http://runnable.com/VSpZzVic6P4hfniR/php-pdo-pagination-example-for-mysql) for implementing PDO Pagination.